# ASP.NET first time with entity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two models that are supposed to be "connected"

```
    public class CategoryClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubCategoryClass> SubCategories { get; set; }

    }
```

And:

```
public class SubCategoryClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryClass CatergoryClass { get; set; }

}
```

I've got this as my DbContext:

```
public class SiteContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SubCategoryClass> SubCategory;
    public DbSet<CategoryClass> Categories;
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartLivingAdvisor.Models.CategoryClass> CategoryClasses { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartLivingAdvisor.Models.SubCategoryClass> SubCategoryClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Now here's the situation, I figured creating a scaffold *wouldn't* automatically assign the characteristic to the SubCategoryClass it's proper CategoryClass. I'm reading this tutorial out of a book, and the book has no further instructions, it simply implied that creating a new SubCategory with the scaffolding would assign the selected Category to the CatergoryClass. (exucse the typo)

I tried this:

var subcategories = db.SubCategoryClass.Include(p => p.CategoryClass.Name);

and attempted it to access it as such:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
       return View(db.SubCategoryClasses.Include(p => p.CatergoryClass).ToList());
    }
```

And here's the view code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CatergoryClass.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But no Name is shown! Help!

How do I assign a CategoryClas to a SubCategoryClass on SubCategoryClass Create?

Comment: You seem to have two DbSet for each of CategoryClass and SubCategoryClass, one with a qualified namespace. It's not clear if those are really the same class or different classes in different namespaces. In your Index() action, try assigning the database result to a variable so you can inspect it in the debugger e.g. `var result = db.SubCategoryClasses.Include(p => p.CatergoryClass).ToList()`. What do you see?

Comment: Ok, So I tried             var result = db.SubCategoryClasses.Include(p => p.CatergoryClass).ToList();
            var resultTwo = db.SubCategory.Include(p => p.CatergoryClass).ToList();  ... resultTwo was an ERROR and the first result upon further inspection, shows me that the CategoryClas is NULL on each of these items. How do I assosciate a CategoryClass with my SubCategoryClass upon Create?

Comment: Fixed! I added this to my Create()  subCategoryClass.CatergoryClass = db.CategoryClasses.Find(subCategoryClass.CategoryID);